# Azure: I don't have permissions, but I am Owner

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azureportal, azure-rbac

I've been added to a RG as `owner` in a subscription outside på company. Navigating to the `Access contol (IAM)` of the RG and clicking "View my access". clearly says "*Grants full access to manage all resources, including the ability to assign roles in Azure RBAC.*":

[image]

But I can not create any resources w/o getting:

```
The client 'mikael.hakansson@xxx.com' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. (Code: AuthorizationFailed) (Code: AuthorizationFailed)
```

Neither can I view Role assignments: "*You do not have permissions to read this directory. Contact a Global Administrator and have them assign you the Directory Readers role in Azure Active Directory.*"

Thank you for any input

Comment: You have to be the owner of subscription , but you have only owner role assigned to resource group.

Comment: When you grant owner access on resource group ,you will see scope as this resource but when you add owner in subscription ,once you open the resource group you will see subscription (inherited).

Comment: If you want to create resources in the subscription/resource group at least you need to have contributor/owner access in subscription . As having owner level access on resource group will not grant you to access the resource providers in the subscription.

Comment: Thank you @AnsumanBal-MT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every type of resource you should be able to create at the subscription level has to have its resource provider registered. This is done in the subscription level (in the resource providers tab in portal; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types)

When the resource provider is registered, Owner or Contributor to a resource group can create that type of resource in the resource group.

However, only the subscription owner can register the resource. It complains about `Microsoft.Storage/register/action` not being permitted when you try to create a storage account, but the `Microsoft.Storage` provider is not registered. Once the subscription administrator registers `Microsoft.Storage`, you should be able to create storage accounts in that resource group with only permissions to that resource group.

Answer (score 3):

As I have mentioned in comments , The `Owner` Role that you have assigned to is in  for the resource Group as its showing `This Resource`. If it was assigned to Subscription then it would have been seen as `Subscription(Inherited)` in the resource group level.

**Example:**

[image]

---

> The client 'mikael.hakansson@xxx.com' with object id 'xxx' does not
> have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Storage/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx' or
> the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh
> your credentials. (Code: AuthorizationFailed) (Code:
> AuthorizationFailed)

Coming to the above error , its because you have permission on only `resource group level`. You need to have access on `Subscription level` which may be `Owner/Contributor`  to create resources. As When you are creating resources `Azure API` registers that `resource provider` on subscription and gets a `token` on your user to create a resource for that resource provider in any resource group on the subscription , if you don't have proper permissions on subscription then it fails to register the resource provider and get the token on your name and returns an error.

Comment: The important part here, however, is, that once the resource provider is registered, owner on the resource group *will* be enough to create the resource there. So the solution shouldn't be to ask for the permission on the subscription level, but to ask the administrator to register that resource provider.

Comment: After 5 hours! Saviour!